# How can I create a new partition with mountpoint by splitting an existing partition?

Tags: partitioning, mountpoint

How can I split an existing partition (NTFS) to get space for a new partition and create a mountpoint for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to boot from a live CD or USB and use [gparted](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gparted) to partition your drive. It should be called something like `Partition Manager` in the System->Administration menu.

Read through [this tutorial for gparted](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html)  - it should tell you everything you need to be able to:

1. Shrink the partition
2. Create a new partition in the free space created by this action

You should take a note of the device path of the partition you create (eg. `/dev/sda5`). To mount this drive you can run this command:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda5 /path/to/mountpoint
```

Replace `ext4` with the file system type, `/dev/sda5` with the device path you noted down and `/path/to/mountpoint` with the file path you want it to be mounted to.

To permanently mount this partition, you need to edit /etc/fstab. Before you do, make a copy to back it up in case you mess it up somehow. To edit /etc/fstab, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`. This will prompt you for your password and then open the file in the text editor.

Once opened, add this line to the end of the file:

```
/dev/sda5       /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

but obviously you need to use your specific information instead. Once you have done this, save and close the file. The partition will now be mounted to the specified path every time you start up the computer.

Comment: which directory is typically taken for the /path/to/mountpoint. mnt or better ? especially under the aspect that i want to move my home directory to the new partition?

Comment: Do you mean your personal `/home/user` or the general `/home` to be on the new partition?

Comment: probably /home would be better i think

Comment: Use `/home` instead of `/path/to/mountpoint`, but make sure you move the contents of `/home` to the new partition first. Use the /etc/fstab method to make it permanent.

Comment: one question still, which partitioning algorithms use ubuntu during he installation, are they available as a standalone application or command? is this gparted?

Comment: I don't know. As far as I know the installer uses the same method as gparted. Perhaps you could ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, thanks so far. Will create a new question.

Comment: The installer doesn't use GParted, although both use libparted for some functionality.

Answer (score 4):

- Install [**gparted**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gparted) [image: Install gparted]
- After installation you can find it under System>>Administration>>Gparted. 
  [image]
- Right click and unmount your NTFS partition first.(In my case i have used /dev/sda6)
- Select your NTFS partition and then right click on it and then choose Resize/Move.
  [image]
- For example i have maximum size of **39998 MB**.
- So now i am giving **30000 MB**
  [image]
- Now goto Edit and choose Apply all Operations. 
  [image]
- After few minutes the opration will get completed. 
  [image]
- Now you will see unallocated space of **9.77 GB**
  [image]
- Right click on the unalloacated space and select New to create new partition.
- Now you are done.

**Note:**

- To learn more about Gparted,you can have a look at this **[tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html)**.