# Permanently mounting Windows' NTFS partition, fully enabled

Tags: windows, dual-boot, permissions, ntfs

I'm transforming a Windows 7 PC into a dual boot system with Ubuntu 10.10. Following [other questions on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9599/how-to-mount-ntfs-drive-at-startup), I've mounted my Windows drive by adding this to fstab

```
UUID=blabla /windows ntfs users,defaults,umask=000 0 0
```

It appears to work well, I can read and write, but it appears to be a bit crippled still. When I tried to update an SVN working copy with [RabbitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org), it complained that it couldn't write to a temporary file inside the working copy, even though the permissions are all on 0777 inside `/windows` (by default, I haven't done that manually). It even [corrupted that working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539227/restoring-the-root-of-a-working-copy) :(

It works when I use the command line SVN client with sudo, but that's hardly user friendly.

Comment: RabbitVCS is linux oriented, it maybe using file types (pipes, symbolic links, etc) or filenames which are not valid for NTFS.

Comment: I'd like to know if you find a solution.  A similar experience happened to me using a NTFS-formatted bridged partition after I edited a Calibre library database in Ubuntu. When accessed in Windows, file access was 1/10 of normal speed in both OS's.  The only solution was to reformat and restore.

Comment: Bart, does it also work with other projects? Never had problems with RabbitVCS, however I do good with the SVN CLI and end up using it more for what I need. Also, most of my data has always been on NTFS. Is it a public project you're using so I could check if I face similar problems? My *fstab* is pretty similar to yours, and has been like that quite a time: "UUID=blablabla /U ntfs-3g uid=1000,gid=4,umask=0,fmask=0,dmask=0 0 0"

Comment: @Charlie Brown: Sorry, the project is not public. I also haven't really tested it with anything else, except the odd read/write of single files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason that you need to work directly on the Windows partition?

NTFS really isn't a good file system to be working on. I'd recommend using an EXT3 or EXT4 file system for your vital work as these are more reliable. If you don't have enough space on your Ubuntu partition, you could boot Windows and shrink its partition then use gparted to create an extra EXT partition to work on.

[How can I create a new partition with mountpoint by splitting an existing partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17388/667)

Comment: I don't *have* to, but it would be more convenient if I didn't have to duplicate some files. I guess it's better to just completely separate it though.

Comment: You might want to wait a couple of hours before accepting my answer - someone might have a better solution that works with your current situation. You should generally wait until there are a few answers before deciding which is best. :)

Comment: My way is generally to accept first and change the accept later, if neccessary. But you have a point :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ntfs-3g instead of ntfs in your fstab. Also make your user owner of mountpoint while mounted `chown user /windows`

Comment: -1 for completely invalid information, ntfs is the ntfs 3g driver, changing the mount dir owner does not affect the privileges on the mounted media