# I can't use the ./ command in USB flash drive

Tags: command-line, usb, bash, permissions, usb-drive

I recently got Linux, and wanted to run the game dwarf fortress in my USB flash drive. To run dwarf fortress on Linux you have to use ./df in the dwarf fortress folder, but when I use this command it says: `bash: ./df: Permission denied`.
This happened a while ago when I wanted to run it in my NTFS partition, but I fixed it (I don't remember how.)
I would like to fix this, thank you.

Comment: probably a permissions problem. Tons of posts on this issue - http://askubuntu.com/questions/209490/permissions-on-automounted-ntfs-drive

Comment: Your file `./df` has exec permission turned off. In usual case, a `sudo chmod +x ./df` can save you already. But, usually it is not the case for NTFS. In addition to @bodhi.zazen, please look at (http://askubuntu.com/questions/30243/why-does-ubuntu-refuse-to-execute-files-from-an-ntfs-partition, http://askubuntu.com/questions/5069/cant-set-permissions-for-files-on-an-ntfs-partition, many more)

Comment: probably permissions problem as mentioned above. Please output `ls -l df` to confirm.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. Anyway, when I use `sudo chmod +x ./df` bash prints the same error as before. Also, using `ls -l df` prints: `-rw-r--r-- 1 joshua joshua 245 Jan 17 22:44 df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

1. Install GParted and plug on your USB drive.
2. Once you opened GParted click the button on the upper-right corner, and select /dev/sdb.
3. Right click on the bar that says /dev/sdb1 and click "unmount".
4. Hover over "format to", then click ntfs.
5. Open the terminal and write `sudo mkdir /media/flash`.
6. Open GParted and repeat step 2, then right click the sdb1 bar and click "properties".
7. Look for the label `UUID:` and copy the text after that (for me it was) `2DC5421719E725AA`.
8. Open the terminal again and write `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`, when gedit is open create a new line and type `UUID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /media/flash ntfs-3g fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000`(replace the `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` with the UUID you copied from GParted).
9. type `sudo umount /dev/stb1` then `sudo mount /media/flash`.

Then you're done! Thanks to the people who helped in the comments.